How does a changing electric field in the secondary wire of a transformer produce a potential difference?
I want to first give a quick rundown to make sure my core concepts are correct.

All charges produce an electric field (and to a degree a magnetic field in the form of a magnetic moment due to the electrons spin).
A magnetic field only impacts the motion of moving particles, not stationary.
Moving particles create a magnetic field.
A changing magnetic field creates a changing electric field, perpendicular to the magnetic field/flux lines.

So in a transformer, on the primary I have a changing magnetic field which induces a changing magnetic field in the secondary which creates a changing electric field in the secondary as well, which causes a potential difference across the windings. Please see my crude image of the secondary coil of a transformer below.

We have a vertical coil of wire, with a magnetic fields flux lines going through the coil. It's AC, so it's a changing magnetic field. This changing magnetic field creates a changing electric field of concentric circles perpendicular to the magnetic field lines. From every single video and article I could find and go through, nobody tackles or illustrates the induced electric field lines. From my understanding, it is the changing electric field that creates the potential difference which essentially drives the current. Based on the illustration above, how I was told the lines work, I cannot see how any meaningful potential develops at points A and B of the coil. Can someone help me visualize or intuitively explain how a potential develops due to this electric field. I am not asking for equations as a form of proof. I understand it mathematically, or at least how the math works, but I can't understand how conceptually it makes any sense. I really just want to be able to visualize it as a way of fundamentally understanding. The way it seems based on my illustration, is that potential would be developing all across each individual coil, but wouldn't create a positive at point A and negative at point B since the electric field seems like it would create A and B at the same potential, i.e. no meaningful potential would develop, it would be the same potential at any point in the coil.

Seemingly you know well that the electric field is circularly around the coil axis just like magnetic field surrounds a wire which has current, so no lack of basic field knowledge.
But you are right - the induced electric field has not a component which is directed upwards or downwards along the helical coil, so how the free electrons in metal could get packed towards A or B? The induced field seems to press them against the wire edge if the wire rises like it does in a helix.
In metal the free electrons have also another reason to move than the induced electric field. The reason is heat. Every free electron gets random kicks to random directions due the random vibrations of the particles . The kicks are given as well by other free electrons as those particles which are bound to their places in the crystal structure.
If an electron is pressed against the tilted wire edge it sooner or later gets a kick which pushes the electron further from the wire edge and the electron can again move along the induced field i.e. climb or fall along the helix.
Another, more mechanical view:

Electron Y has drifted rightwards due the induced electric field and got stuck at the wire edge. Electron X is also drifting rightwards due the force (=red) caused by the induced field. Electron Y pushes it away with some force (green),
The force resultant (blue, drawn separately) to electron X is not rightwards, but along the coil wire.

What you want to study is Faraday's law of induction. You are discussing the electromotive force induced by the varying magnetic flux. It's proportional to the negative of the first derivative of the flux with respect to time.
Your thinking has a problem because when you place a conductor in an electric field, the potential on the conductor is the same throughout (assuming the whole thing is much smaller than the wavelength), so you would not get an EMF.

Let's assume that the wires are perfect conductors. In reality, of course, they are not, because they have some resistance, but that resistance is irrelevant here, so it's best if we ignore it.
It's important to recognize that there is no "electric field in the secondary wire." After all, it's a conductor! As you know, you can't generate an electric field in a conductor. Transformers are no exception to this rule.
In particular, the following is not what happens:

So in a transformer, on the primary I have a changing magnetic field which induces a changing magnetic field in the secondary which creates a changing electric field in the secondary as well, which causes a potential difference across the windings.

Here's what actually happens. There's a changing magnetic field around the primary winding, which creates an electric field around the primary, too. On a small scale (if we were to look in between one turn and the next, say), that electric field is parallel to the wire.
If, for some reason, the secondary winding were made out of an insulator like silk or plastic, then yes, there would be an electric field in the secondary winding. Obviously, we don't build transformers like that; instead, we make the secondary winding out of a conductor.
Since it's impossible for an electric field to exist inside a conductor, the secondary winding has to do something to neutralize that electric field. There are two things that can happen:

The charge inside the secondary winding can get rearranged, so that we have positive and negative electrostatic charges on the wire. These charges will extend all the way out to the outside of the transformer, where we can measure the resulting voltage with a voltmeter.
The secondary winding can conduct a current, producing an electric field that cancels out the electric field created by the current conducted by the primary wiring.

If the secondary winding is unconnected, then only #1 will occur (except that a tiny amount of #2 will occur, too, because of the capacitance of the secondary winding). If it's short-circuited, then only #2 will occur (maybe a tiny amount of #1, I'm not sure). If the secondary winding is connected to a reasonable load, both things will occur.

A time-varying magnetic flux creates a non-conservative electric field. The key difference here is that the electric field in this scenario does not come from a potential difference (as in static fields) but instead arises from Faraday's Law of Induction. Faraday’s law tells us that the induced electric field forms closed loops around the changing magnetic flux (like concentric circles around the coil’s axis in your image). So this field doesn't create a potential difference in the same way as static electric fields do (no conservative "radial" field that would have a starting point and an ending point).
Here are two loops weakly coupled since the gap is approaching the wire diameter.
Notice when you slide the wire gap smaller the particles accelerate more between the loops and in greater flux density, meaning greater mutual coupling or less leakage.
Here is a model
 

Thinking about absolute value of A and B potentials from prim. potential point doesn’t make much sense since they are dependent on mutual properties of prim. and sec. coils how they are physically wind.
This properties affect the impedance between coils (resistance, capacity) causing the sec. voltages flies somehow from primary point of view.
So better is to think just about potential difference between A and B.
